# Does non-taxable, international organization wage count as "Earned Income" on 2441 line 5?

Tags: income-tax, non-resident

I am a US resident married to a non-citizen G4 visa holder employed at the United Nations. My wife made the election to be treated as a tax resident (6013G) last year and we filed with no issues . We are filing jointly again this year and our situation has been straightforward with the exception of how to claim "Child and Dependent Care Expenses" for our child. The instructions say that I and my spouse must have "earned income" to be eligible but her income is non-taxable.

On Form 2441 (https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/f2441.pdf) for line number 5 (spouse income) it says:

*If married filing jointly, enter your spouse’s earned income (if you or your spouse was a student or was disabled, see the instructions); all others, enter the amount from line 4* ......

My questions is:
Does my wife's UN income count as "Earned income" for the purpose of Child support deduction as described on line 5 of 2441?

I have already consulted 2 accountants without getting a definitive opinion. Where in the tax code can I get a definition of "Earned Income"?